# Declaring variables jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, var

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("aaa") > -1)
{
    $("#wrap").css({display: 'block'});
    $("#nav").css({display: 'block'});
}
if (window.location.href.indexOf("bbb") > -1)
{
    $("#wrap").css({display: 'block'});
    $("#nav").css({display: 'block'});
}
if (window.location.href.indexOf("ccc") > -1)
{
    $("#wrap").css({display: 'block'});
    $("#nav").css({display: 'block'});
}
...
```

Is it possible to:

```
var url = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"......]

if (window.location.href.indexOf(url) > -1)
{
    $("#wrap").css({display: 'block'});
    $("#nav").css({display:'block'});
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how the title relates to the question.

Comment: Does not show any research from OPs part. Had OP ran this and tested and it did not work - there is no evidence of that. Also how is this related to jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` for looping through array elements:

```
var url = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
{
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(url[i]) > -1)
    {
        $("#wrap").css({display: 'block'});
        $("#nav").css({display: 'block'});
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i appreciate you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, but you can for example use the `grep` method to look through the items in the array:

```
var url = ["aaa","bbb","ccc", ... ];
var href = window.location.href;

if ($.grep(url, function(u) { return href.indexOf(u) != -1; }).length) {
  $("#wrap,#nav").css({ display: 'block' });
}
```

Comment: i appreciate you for helping me.